How to export embedded ttf fonts into ttf files with itext in Java?
I have to export embedded ttf fonts from a PDF file to valid ttf files. I have found a code snippet in the knowledge base of itext which can unembedd fonts in a PDF file. But I can't find a way how to write the fonts to files in order to save them before unembedding.
I have dived into the itext code and could not figure out how to transform a PdfFont to bytes[] or something. There is a snippet for embedding fonts using a PdfStream based on the bytes from the font file:
// The font file
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fontfile, "r");
byte fontbytes[] = new byte[(int) raf.length()];
raf.readFully(fontbytes);
raf.close();

// Create a new stream for the font file
PdfStream stream = new PdfStream(fontbytes);
stream.setCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
stream.put(PdfName.Length1, new PdfNumber(fontbytes.length));


...

// Embed the passed font to the pdf document
fontDictionary.put(PdfName.FontFile2, stream.makeIndirect(pdfDoc).getIndirectReference());

I tried to reverse the procedure but cannot figure out how to do it using the PdfIndirectReference.
Can the PdfWriter be used for the task? Or do I really need to work with glyphs?

Worth noting that extracting fonts from a PDF is a very questionable practice in terms of font licensing. In other words, most PDF library/software developers won't include these extraction features on purpose to avoid potential legal issues. If you believe a used font is free: check the used/embedded fonts and search for a suitable download link providing a full font-family download. Even if the embedded subsets are based on freely available fonts they are most likely subsets and missing a lot of features (e.g kerning data, substitution features like ligatures)

@KJ: Yes the question is similar, but for C# / iTextSharp. I know that the API for Java and C# should be similar or is the same but still in my opinion the difference is important. Maybe somebody knows a solution in Java but with different libraries. I adapted the title. The question has been asked 14 years ago and still there is no solution for the problem. The only relevant answer with code suggests to start an external tool and does not provide a solution for the question about iText/ iTextSharp. But it is a good hint to use an external tool.

@herrstrietzel: In my case the extraction of fonts is not a problem because it is for the document owner who already has the rights. And embedded fonts usually do not contain the complete fonts but only subsets, as you said. Some/many of the necessary font tables are missing. In my opinion it would not make any sense to use embedded fonts for other purposes (distribution, ...).

Here is another helpful question where some external tools are mentioned for the font extraction:
How can I extract embedded fonts from a PDF as valid font files?
There is no itext/Java solution.
